# Background-size: cover not scaling image in div

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have four equally sized div's set up like this:

```
<div id="top-left"></div>
<div id="top-right"></div>
<div id="bottom-left"></div>
<div id="bottom-right"></div>
```

Each is 50% of the page's width and positioned absolutely. Like this, for example:

```
#top-right {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 50%;
width: 50%;
height: 50%;
}
```

The issue is when I try to scale a (large) background image via the CSS3 cover. This is the background image css I have so far:

```
background: #000 url('DSC01992.jpg') center center fixed no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-(etc.)
```

Here is a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/TqQv7/

If you open the placeholder image here: http://placekitten.com/2000/1000  you will see that the image is not being scaled correctly.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm getting a 502 on your second link, man

Comment: They both are working for me...

Comment: It is being scaled, but cover makes the BG image as big as possible. What is your intended behavior?

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks Each div responds to the window's size, so the background image needs to also scale accordingly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Removing the `background-position` and `background-attachment` portions of your short-hand `background` declaration will give you your desired results.

Change:

```
background: #000 url('http://placekitten.com/2000/1000') center center fixed no-repeat;
```

To:

```
background: #000 url('http://placekitten.com/2000/1000') no-repeat;
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TqQv7/1/

Using <s>`background-position` and</s> `background-attachment` along with `background-size : cover` is anti-intuitive, you're telling the browser to do two different things there, and it seems that modern browsers still default to the old method rather than the new.

For more information about caveats regarding `background-size` check-out the MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size

Comment: I think you can keep `center center`, it's just `fixed` which is causing it to scale to the window dimensions, rather than the container div dimensions

Comment: verified, just removing 'fixed' "fixed" the issue :D

Comment: Indeed, taking the "fixed" off fixes the issue...but what if I want to have a fixed contained image on a div? 
Thanks